# Convertir a poligonos y puntos los valores de un archivo en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo en mi Pc, texto.txt que contiene estos valores

```
5 0, 6 1, 5 2, 4 1 | 5 1
1 1, 4 1, 4 4, 1 4 | 3 3
1 1, 3 3, 4 1, 3 0 | 3 4
```

y necesito convertir a polígonos todos los valores antes del símbolo |, y a puntos los últimos 2 valores, salida correcta seria así:

```
poligonos = [[(5,0), (6, 1), (5, 2), (4, 1)],
               [(1,1), (4,1), (4, 4), (1, 4)],
               [(1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 1), (3, 0)]
              ]

puntos = [[(5,1)],[(3,3)],[(3,4)]]
```

en mi avance intento recuperar polígonos así:

```
texto = 'texto.txt'
archivo = open(texto)
if archivo is not None:
    poligonos = []
    puntos = []
    valores = archivo.readlines()
    for x in valores:
        a1, a2 = x.split('|')
        poligonos.append(a1.strip().split(' '), a2.strip().split(' '))
    print(poligonos)
```

y en la parte de `poligonos.append(a1.strip().split(' '), a2.strip().split(' '))` me arroja  `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

¿Cómo seria la forma de separar en polígonos y puntos?,gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como el propio error te indica estas intentando agregar dos elementos a la lista mediante `list.append`. Este método solo recibe un parámetro y agrega este parámetro como elemento al final de la lista, para añadir más de uno debes usar `list.extend`, que recibe un iterable como argumento.

De todas formas **estás intentando agregar tanto el punto como los vértices a la lista `polígonos`.** Además, deberías separar el valor `x` e `y` de cada coordenada y hacer un casting a `int` de ellas.

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
poligonos, puntos = [], []
with open ("texto.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        vertices, punto = line.split(" | ")
        poligonos.append([tuple(int(c) for c in  vertice.split())
                                           for vertice in vertices.split(", ")])
        puntos.append([tuple(int(c) for c in punto.split())])
```

Por cada fila hacemos por tanto los siguientes pasos:

- Separamos la parte de la cadena que contiene los vértices de la que contiene el punto. Para ello usamos " | " como separador:

  ```
  >>> linea = "1 1, 3 3, 4 1, 3 0 | 3 4"
  >>> vertices, punto = line.split(" | ")
  >>> vertices
  "1 1, 3 3, 4 1, 3 0"
  >>> punto
  "3 4"
  ```
- Obtenemos cada par de coordenadas de cada vértice, para ello separamos por ", ":

  ```
   >>> vertices = "1 1, 3 3, 4 1, 3 0"
   >>> vertices.split(", ")
   ['1 1', '3 3', '4 1', '3 0']
  ```
- Ahora tenemos separados cada vértice pero queremos separar las coordenadas `x`, e `y` y almacenarlas en una tupla. También debemos hacer un casting a cada coordenada a `int` para luego operar con ellas sin problemas:

  ```
  >>> vertices = ['1 1', '3 3', '4 1', '3 0']
  >>> [vertice.split() for vertice in vertices]
  [['1', '1'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '0']]

  >>> [int(coord) for coord in vertice.split() for vertice in vertices]
  [[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 1], [3, 0]]

  >>> [tuple(int(coord) for coord in vertice.split()) for vertice in vertices]
  [(1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 1), (3, 0)]
  ```
- Por último, el punto es tratado igual que un vértice.

Salida:

```
>>> poligonos
[[(5, 0), (6, 1), (5, 2), (4, 1)],
 [(1, 1), (4, 1), (4, 4), (1, 4)],
 [(1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 1), (3, 0)]]

>>> puntos
[[(5, 1)],
 [(3, 3)],
 [(3, 4)]]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla , por tu genial respuesta , no tenia claro de list.extend.

Comment: Holà FJ ¿Es `tuple(int(c) for c in  vertice.split())` para cada columna ? Ps: joyeux Noël !

Comment: Hola @Marine1. Aplicamos `tuple(int(c) for c in vertice.split())` por cada par de coordenadas que forma un punto, es decir sobre cadenas del tipo `"1 7"` con el fin de obtener `(1, 7)`. He editado la pregunta desgranando los `for` anidados. ¡Feliz Navidad! ;)